# Find residues of a function $f(z) = z^{10}e^{\frac{1}{2z}} + \frac{z+4\pi}{z-4\pi}\cot{\frac{z}{2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series, singularity

I am trying to find residues at singularity points of this function, but I cannot wrap my head around its Laurent series. Singularity points are $2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}.$ $f$ is a sum of two functions and $0$ is an essential singularity for both of them. Should I conclude it is an essential singularity for $f$? Not sure, since some terms could cancel out. It is easy to show that $-4\pi$ is a removable singularity. For $k \neq -2$, I have no idea.

Comment: Clearly $0$ is essential, but I don't think any terms should be cancel out. the coefficients of $z^{10}e^\frac1z$ aren't the same as coefficients of other part.

Comment: This is ugly enough I would just use Mathematica. Any reason you haven't already?

Comment: I did use WolframAlpha to get an idea about how the series of the function look like, but it is a homework question and I have to rigorously and by hand show each step of my conclusion. I was wondering if there are any shortcuts (i.e. useful claims/observations) which I may not see at the moment.

Comment: @Nosrati Thanks! Actually, when I said “some terms could cancel out” I was aware they wouldn’t, but didn’t know how to explicitly show it because I don’t know how to write down the Laurent series of that particular  function around singularity points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $0$ is an essential singularity of $z^{10}e^{1/2z}$, but not of $\frac{z+4\pi}{z-4\pi}\cot\left(\frac z2\right)$. So, $0$ is an essential singularity of $f$.

Anyway,$$\cot\left(\frac z2\right)=\frac2{z-4\pi}-\frac16(z-4\pi)+\cdots,$$and so$$\frac{\cot\left(\frac z2\right)}{z-4\pi}=\frac2{(z-4\pi)^2}-\frac16+\cdots$$It follows from this that\begin{align}\frac{z+4\pi}{z-4\pi}\cot\left(\frac z2\right)&=\bigl((z-4\pi)+8\pi\bigr)\left(\frac2{(z-4\pi)^2}-\frac16+\cdots\right)\\&=\frac{16\pi}{(z-4\pi)^2}+\frac2{z-4\pi}-\frac{4\pi}3+\cdots\end{align}and therefore$$\operatorname{rez}_{z=4\pi}\frac{z+4\pi}{z-4\pi}\cot\left(\frac z2\right)=2.$$So, the residue of $f$ at $4\pi$ is $2$.

On the other hand.$$\operatorname{res}_{z=0}z^{10}\exp\left(\frac1{2z}\right)=\frac1{2^{11}11!}$$and\begin{align}\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\frac{z+4\pi}{z-4\pi}\cot\left(\frac z2\right)&=\lim_{z\to0}z\frac{z+4\pi}{z-4\pi}\cot\left(\frac z2\right)\\&=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z+4\pi}{z-4\pi}\frac{\cos\left(\frac z2\right)}{\sin\left(\frac z2\right)/z}\\&=\frac{0+4\pi}{0-4\pi}\frac{\cos(0)}{1/2}\\&=-2.\end{align}Therefore,$$\operatorname{res}_{z=0}f(z)=\frac1{2^{11}11!}-2.$$

Comment: Oh, true, I realise now that $0$ is a pole of 1st order of that second function. When you calculated the series for $\cot{\frac{z}{2}}$ you did it around $4\pi$, how come you calculated residue at $z = 0$ using only the coefficient from the $z^{10}e^{\frac{1}{2z}}$? I also have the same question about $4\pi$, where you calculated the residue using only coeff.from the second function. Thanks a lot for providing an answer!

Comment: I forgot about it! Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. If I am not mistaken, it also remains to be edited for the point $4\pi$.

Comment: Why is that? The residue of $z^{10}\exp\left(\frac1{2z}\right)$ at $4\pi$ is $0$.

Comment: Oh yes, because it is a removable singularity for $z^{10}exp{\frac{1}{2z}}$. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.